# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for use 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to uninstall php and phpmyadmin on my machine that has Linux Mint, but when I go to uninstall the database for phpmyadmin, in the panel that appears when installing and uninstalling phpmyadmin from the terminal I get this message:

```
An error occurred while deleting the database:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user                            
'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`debian-sys-maint` is a system user that the package manager uses for performing administrative tasks. It seems you've either removed that user or changed the password. The password is stored on disk at `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

Probably the best solution is to reconfigure the database server, probably with `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` or `dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server` (although those are metapackages, so there's a chance you'd need to use the specific version such as `dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server-10.5` but offhand I don't think that will be needed).

Reconfiguring the package will cause the package manager to recreate the debian-sys-maint user and from there it will be able to remove the phpMyAdmin package.